# Django Package tests not found

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a weird problem at hand.

I'm creating a django package and would like to provide some test cases for it.

The package is named ajax_forms and the full path is part of my PYTHONPATH.
This directory also contains a tests directory (with the `__init__.py` file) a tests.py file (containing the tests) and a urls.py file.

Now I want to run the tests.

The ajax_forms parent directory has an example project setup with ajax_forms in INSTALLED_APPS.

But I can't seem to let the tests run:

```
 >> ./manage.py test ajax_forms
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

No tests are found so I try to be more specific:

```
 >> ./manage.py test ajax_forms.tests
....
raise ValueError("Test label '%s' does not refer to a test" % label)
ValueError: Test label 'ajax_forms.tests' does not refer to a test
(ajax-validation)
```

Even ./manage.py ajax_forms.tests.tests.AjaxFormViewTest will not find the tests and gives the same error as above.

But trying to import the test case from the ./manage.py shell works fine

```
In [2]: from ajax_forms.tests.tests import AjaxFormViewTest
```

I'm kinda clueless here, on what's going on.

Comment: Is that file in the tests package really called **`init.py`**? Instead of `__init__.py`?

Comment: Sorry that should have been _____init_____.py instead of init.py. So there's no problem there I think.

Comment: You did it again :) Use backticks (\` \`) to mark up code snippets or filenames, then they won't get mangled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put `from tests import *` in your `__init__.py` file

Django will look in your app for a package/module called tests, and then interrogate its namespace for test cases. In this case it will look at the namespace of your tests package (from the **init**.py file), and discover nothing there. By doing the import in the `__init__.py` file then you will import the testcases from your tests module into the namespace of the tests package, and django will be able to locate them and run them.

Comment: Of course, if you've only got one file inside the tests directory, there's no point in having that directory at all: just move the tests.py file to the level above.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is to use more inteligent tests runner. You can try `nose` and `django_nose` - it will discover tests in this case. If you don't want to install aditional apps, @Ctrlspc solution is the only way to solve this problem.

Comment: I have just started using django-nose and I can recommend this approach too, I like the fact that you can easily get converge and other nose goodies, but baked into django!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `models.py` file inside the app, add the new app to the installed apps and django will find the tests.py file without having to add anything to the `__init__.py`.

I guess both @Ctrlspc approach and this one are sort of dirty. so any choice is ok