# Can I run django tests (manage.py) from a different directory?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a pretty standard Django test case setup (I think)

```
api-name
    manage.py
    api-name
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        wsgi.py
    v0
        project
            stuff.py
            tests
                test_stuff.py
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api-name.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api-name.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**test_stuff.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from v0.project.stuff import *


class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # set stuff up

    def test_project_stuff(self):
        # test stuff

    def test_other_stuff(self):
        # test stuff
```

Here's what happens when I execute tests:

```
[cwilbur api-name]$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.014s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
[cwilbur api-name]$ cd ..
[cwilbur source]$ ./api-name/manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Is this (tests run from the project's root directory, but not from elsewhere) expected behavior? Is there a way to change things so that it will work (I want to execute my tests from a pre-commit hook in a different directory)?

I tried adding `from tests import *` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413069/99640), but it didn't help. I also tried moving the `sys.path.append` line from wsgi.py to manage.py, but that didn't help either.

Any other ideas out there I can try?

Comment: You could just add `cd` command to your pre-commit hook.

Comment: @dizballanze That has the disadvantage that I have to add another cd at the end of the command and before any intervening exits to get back to where I started and have no side effects. Don't get me wrong, I'll do it if there's no other way.

Comment: If you use bash, you can try run manage.py in subshell like this: `(cd /somedir; ./manage.py test)` this will not create any side effects.

Answer (score 16):

Late in answering this question. But hope this helps someone:

`python <project_path>/manage.py test <your_project_dir>`

[image: Running Django tests from another directory]

From Django documentation:

> You can also provide a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory:
>
> ```
> $ ./manage.py test animals/
> ```

References:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful if you are running tests from a Makefile located outside your app directory.

Comment: Great answer, saved me from a headache !

Comment: @Martin exactly what I was trying to achieve ! It works perfectly with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments from @dizballanze and feedback from review of the code, I wound up doing this:

```
(cd /somedir && python manage.py test)
```

I'm still curious as to whether it's possible to run the tests without cding into the root directory of the project, though.